# Does List.equals() performed intended behavior while overriding java.lang.Object.equals()?

Tags: java, arraylist

Let's say I have this ArrayList in a class:

```
private ArrayList<Integer> someList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

If I'm overriding the java.lang.equals() method in a class containing the ArrayList, and I want to compare if another Object's ArrayList is equal:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
  this.someList.equals(o.someList);
}
```

Would the ArrayList equals method work in comparing the size and contents of the other ArrayList, or would it just call the current overriden equals method?

Comment: Why don't you try first? Learning to program is about curiosity and making experiments. And for example about researching javadoc documentation.

Comment: Why would it call the overridden method if the method is on the class that _contains_ the list?

Comment: Because they both had the same name, so I wasn't sure which it would do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ArrayList` instance calls it's equals method. The overwritten equals method can be called only from instances of your class. So the answer is yes, it will work in comparing the size and contents of the other `ArrayList`.